# Cannot create a user in IPA server for remote login

Tags: centos, certificate-authority, freeipa, identity-management

I had created a new IPA IdM server in Centos 7 using script `install-ipa-server.` The installation was successful. After installation, I was not able to create a user using IPA user-add user, it asks for first name and lastname, but after that it shows an error as following:

```
ipa: ERROR: cert validation failed for "CN=server.example.com,0=EXAMPLE.COM" ((SEC_ERROR_UNTRUSRED_ISSSUER) Peer's certificate issuer has been masked as not trusted by the user.) 
ipa: ERROR: cannot connect to 'https://server.example.com/ipa/xml': (SEC ERROR_UNTRUSTED_ISSUER) Peer's certificate issuer has been masked as not trusted by the user.
```

Also, I am not able to connect to the IPA server via browser using https://server.example.com (which is the host name of the IdM server machine and configured in `/etc/hosts` file to direct to the server IP). It ends up at website not found error.

Where I went wrong?

Comment: Could you please give details about version of ipa-server rpm and installation log file located at `/var/log/ipaserver-install.log` ?

Comment: what version? ipa 4.2.0 or ipa 4.4.0? did you follow http://www.freeipa.org/page/Deployment_Recommendations Did you setup a new PKI CA? Use a parent CA? did you add the CA you built as trusted by the system?

Answer (score 0):

Check that IPA is running by  running  ipactl status -- ensure that all services are running .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you aren't trusting your new CA, make sure your CA cert is trusted.

you can do this by connecting to your ipa interface with sclient

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server.example.com:443 </dev/null
```

the CA cert is either the second (default) or 3rd (if IPA is a subordinate/intermediate CA)

Check it with the list of certs trusted (it should be the first one)

```
less /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
```

if not, there's a decent article on how to add this CA to your trust manually.
Install the ca-certificates package:

> yum install ca-certificates
>
> Enable the dynamic CA configuration feature:
>
> update-ca-trust force-enable
>
> Add it as a new file to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/:
>
> cp foo.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
>
> Use command:
>
> update-ca-trust extract

http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html